# Saving features to SQL Server using Openlayers and geoserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, openlayers, geoserver

I am using the SQL Server plugin for geoserver (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html) to show some geometries using WMS. This works fine. I am also able to extract geometries as vectors without much trouble.

Now I need to add the retrieved vector to another layer and save it to a table in the SQL Server database. This is causing some problems.

This is some of the code:

```
saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();
saveStrategy.events.register("success", '', ChangesSuccess);
saveStrategy.events.register("fail", '', ChangesFailed);

function ChangesSuccess(e) {
    alert('Done');
}

function ChangesFailed(e) {
    alert('Failed');
}

selectionLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        "SelectionLayer",
        {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy]
            , projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:25832")
            , protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                version: "1.1.0",
                url: "http://someserver.cloudapp.net:8181/geoserver/wfs",
                featurePrefix: 'xxxx',
                featureType: "xxxxxxxxx",
                featureNS: "xxx.xxx/xxx",
                geometryName: "xxxxx"
            })
            , displayInLayerSwitcher: false
        });

selectControl.events.register("featureselected", this, function (e) {
    var feat = e.feature;
    feat.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;
    selectionLayer.addFeatures([feat]);
    saveStrategy.save();
);
```

When I try to save the newly added feature I get the following exception in the fail event of the save strategy:

> "java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.geotools.jdbc.BasicSQLDialect.encodeGeometryValue(Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;ILjava/lang/StringBuffer;)V org.geotools.jdbc.BasicSQLDialect.encodeGeometryValue(Lcom/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry;ILjava/lang/StringBuffer;)V"

I don't know what to try from here, but if someone has encountered this before or has some suggestions on what could be the issue I am more than happy to hear about it.. It is 1:50am here now and are probably not going to bed before this is fixed so all suggestions are more than welcome :)